# Deleting Old Records from Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift3

I've been programming with xcode and swift 3 for four days and have already found these pages to be hugely helpful. The problem I've run into is in my attempt to delete old, redundant records from my Core Data entity. I can add records that are date stamped, but once that date is in the past, I want to get rid of the record. Here's what I have so far, which is giving me an error that suggests the problem is in how I'm assigning the value in start_time to thenDate. Is it something obvious that I'm missing?

```
func DeleteOldRecords() -> Void {
    let deleteContext = getContext()
    let nowDate = Date()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "table")

    let result = try? deleteContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultData = result as! [table]

    for object in resultData {
        let thenDate = deleteContext.value(forKey: "start_time") as! Date
        if thenDate < nowDate {
            deleteContext.delete(object)
        }
    }

    do {
        try deleteContext.save()
    }
    catch {

    }
}

func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key start_time.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the date from the `viewContext` rather than from a `NSManagedObject` and the context *is not key value coding-compliant for the key start_time*.

I suppose it's

```
let thenDate = object.value(forKey: "start_time") as! Date
```

But you can save a lot of work if you perform a fetch using a predicate `start_date < now`. That will return all records to be deleted.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Leaps right out as soon as you mentioned it. Thanks a million. That was driving me crazy!